# Google login token to localstorage (React)

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am still quite new to this and in need of help. I am building a log in, which includes "Log in with Google".

I have the following Google authentication I am using to log into a PrivateRoute. For the route to be accessible, the jwt token needs to be stored locally (as is the one that is not created through Google, but locally). This is my google login:

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['email', 'profile']
}));


router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    let user = req.user
    console.log('user :', user);
    const payload = {
        user: {
            id: user.id
        }
    }
    jwt.sign(
        payload,
        keys.secret,
        {
            expiresIn: 2592000
        },
        (err, token) => {
            res.redirect('/?code=' + token);

        }
    );
    //redirect to front-end
    res.redirect('/?code=' + token);
    window.localStorage.setItem('bearer' + token)
});
```

But I cannot seem to store it, meaning take it from the address bar and store it in the application. Thanks for any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I did in my PrivateRoute:

```
{localStorage.setItem("token", window.location.search.split("=")[1])}
```